# More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'

Tags: java, android

I'm facing this following problem when I try build my app:

> More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'

I already tried solve including these excludes in my app/build.gradle:

```
    packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
}
```

... and the problem persists

**I'm using Java 8 and the last stable version of Android Studio**

Comment: just send you error log pls

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

Just add this on packagingOptions:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
}
```